# Why won't it loop?

Tags: vba, excel

The auto scroll works fine, but I'm trying to get this to loop back around but once it returns to A1, it just stops and the macro seemingly is done. What did I do wrong?

```
 Sub ReRunMacro()
 Dim xMin As String
 Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim validSheets() As Variant

 Set ws = ActiveSheet

 validSheets = Array("CNC Machining Cell 2", "CNC Grinding Cell", "CNC Turning Cell 1 & 3", "CNC Turning Cell 2")

 If UBound(Filter(validSheets, ws.Name)) = -1 Then 
 Exit Sub 
 End If

 lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 1 To 14 Step 2


       Cells(i, 1).Select
       ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1
       Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
       If i = lastRow - 2 Or i = lastRow - 1 Then
       i = 0
       Cells(1, 1).Select
    End If
  Next i
  Range("A1").Activate

  End Sub
```

Comment: mayber your `lastrow` is greater than16?

Comment: As @ScottCraner said, does it ever even get into the `If` statement? Have you tried debugging and stepping through to see where the issue is?

Comment: Step through your code using **F8** and check the values of your variables. Possible logic error

Comment: @urdearboy when I debug it keeps running through the loop but when I actually run the macro, it just returns to A1 and stops.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do anything except activate A1.

Comment: @SJR so how would I get it to loop back around and repeat?

Comment: repeat till when, right now if you got it working it would never end as it would start the loop over and over again.  It would probably help if you discussed what you are actually trying to accomplish in the code.

Comment: @ScottCraner trying to get it to auto scroll down, loop back to A1 and then repeat over and over (we run a job board in the shop where some of the tables are cut off, so this would allow them to be visible, then loop and repeat)

Comment: for how long, forever?  change `For i = 1 To 14 Step 2` to `For i = 1 To lastRow Step 2` and append all `Range(..` and `Cells(...` with `ws.`

Answer (score 0):

The following example will scroll forever. But I suggest to use `DoEvents` and a stop switch otherwise it will really run forever and will not be stoppable.

```
Option Explicit

Public StopScroll As Boolean 'global switch to stop scrolling

Public Sub ScrollForever()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 1

    StopScroll = False 'initialize scroll

    Do
        DoEvents 'make excel responsive
        If StopScroll Then Exit Sub 'possibility to stop the scroll again

        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = iRow
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

        iRow = iRow + 1 'count 1 row up (change it to 2 for step 2)
        iRow = IIf(iRow > LastRow, 1, iRow) 'if last row is reached reset to 1
    Loop While iRow <= LastRow 'this is never true because of the line above and therefore runs forever
End Sub
```

You can use the following eg. for a button to stop scrolling:

```
Public Sub StopIt()
    StopScroll = True
End Sub
```

Comment: When I ran this, it just froze halfway through the first scroll.

Comment: Well, I tested it and it works as expected. Try to go through it step by step with F8 to see what happens and check the values of the variables. Copy it into a new workbook and eg fill 10 rows in column A with data to test it.

Comment: I got it; I just threw a do...loop around the autoscroll statement I had and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So All I did to the aforementioned code was add a do...loop and it now repeats:

```
 Sub ReRunMacro()
  Dim xMin As String
  Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim validSheets() As Variant

  Set ws = ActiveSheet

  validSheets = Array("CNC Machining Cell 2", "CNC Grinding Cell", "CNC Turning Cell 1 & 3", "CNC Turning Cell 2")

  If UBound(Filter(validSheets, ws.Name)) = -1 Then 
  Exit Sub 
  End If

  lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Do
  For i = 1 To 14 Step 2
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        If i = lastRow - 2 Or i = lastRow - 1 Then
        i = 0
        Cells(1, 1).Select
     End If
   Next i
   Range("A1").Activate
 Loop

 End Sub
```